# Receiving to unknown address?

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app, receiving, lost-transactions

I'm using Bitcoin Wallet by Bitcoin Wallet Developers version 10.06 and I'm still waiting for money and this is my first time using it and I gave them my sending address by accident which is the second address under the top address by accident but I haven't received anything...what will happen or can I receive this here!?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean with an "unknown receiving address". Do you mean that you are using the address for the first time, that your wallet does not recognize the address itself, that your counterparty expected you to use a pre-registered address, or something else entirely?

Comment: I went to addresses and I chose the Second Bitcoin address (Unknown) just below the top address that says receiving address.. Duh..  I admit I totally screwed up but it was an honest mistake. Please Help Me

Comment: Could you please edit your post to add what wallet software you are using? Perhaps a screenshot (please feel free hide any private information) would help.

Comment: I'm using Bitcoin Wallet from Bitcoin Wallet Developers version 10.06

Comment: Have you checked whether the address you gave has been paid on a block explorer such as e.g. blockstream.info or mempool.space?

Comment: I just confirmed that I gave them my Sending address instead of my receiving address.. will it be returned to them!? If so.. how long will it take!?

Comment: Yes and it says zero blocks received so was it returned!?

Comment: No, it means that the transaction is still unconfirmed. Possibly the sender could still correct the error by replacing that transaction.

Comment: I confirmed it's NOT received throughout blockchain or mempool

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, it sounds like you previously received a payment on your wallet. Let’s call this *transaction A*. When trying to receive a second payment, you accidentally gave the address of an input from *transaction A* instead of your own receive address, and the payer in the second payment paid the address you indicated.

You could try to reach out to the party that paid you in *transaction A*. If they directly control the funds, they may be able to return them to you. If the sender in *transaction A* used some custodial wallet, the address may be associated with a completely different user, though. If so, possibly the service could help, but more likely, it would be unrecoverable.

Comment: I have never paid or received any payments from anyone ever on Bitcoin Wallet. I mistakenly gave them my Sending address instead of my receiving address but nothing is showing up and I checked on blockchain.info and mempool.. this is my sending address:

Comment: bc1qnrxg3gz2zc9ppgtvgtfkvax7mpdgc7wasjjn56

Comment: I'm very confused what "sending address" could mean if you've never sent any transactions. It's not like wallets have separate addresses for incoming or outgoing transactions; addresses are just for receiving.

Comment: In Bitcoin Wallet if you click the second icon in the top right it says "Addresses" then the first address specifically says "Receiving address" then  there's two addresses below that which are Sending addresses and I gave them my Sending address by mistake

Comment: No money has been sent to bc1qnrxg3gz2zc9ppgtvgtfkvax7mpdgc7wasjjn56 so ask whoever says they sent money to give you the transaction-id